# Drupal 7 -Translate content field on user profile

Tags: drupal

I'm building a multilingual site (with i18n module and entity translation). I've added a field collection  on user profile type (with profile2 module ). How can user translate the content of the field collection of here profile   ?

knowing that I have this error message with entity translation

The entities of type Field collection item do not define a valid base path: it will not be possible to translate them.

The entities of type Node registration do not define a valid base path: it will not be possible to translate them.

The entities of type Profil do not define a valid base path: it will not be possible to translate them.

I have activate "Users may translate this field".

thank you

Comment: Better fit for http://drupal.stackexchange.com/